# Can't find an OpenSequentialWriteAsync() method on StorageFile

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-winrt

This is written in C++/winRT which will eventually replace C++/CX. 
The following 3 lines of code precede what should be a request to 
`OpenSequentialWriteAsync()`. but alas, there is not such command, only
 `OpenSequentialReadAsync()`.

Is there a reason that creating a sequential file is not allowed???

```
StorageFolder _storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder();    

StorageFolder _turboCalc = co_await _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc", CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists); //create sub folder in folder

StorageFile  _storageFile = co_await _turboCalc.CreateFileAsync(L"FileDoubles.dbo", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting); //create file in sub folder
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for a meaningless feature based on a misunderstanding of how the system works isn't going to be helpful to anyone. (Read-ahead caching isn't a meaningful optimization for writing a file.)

Answer (score 1):

Windows has different [caching strategies for files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#caching_behavior). As noted at that link (this is for `CreateFile`, which is at a lower level than `StorageFile`):

> Specifying the `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` flag can increase
>   performance for applications that read large files using sequential
>   access. Performance gains can be even more noticeable for applications
>   that read large files mostly sequentially, but occasionally skip
>   forward over small ranges of bytes. If an application moves the file
>   pointer for random access, optimum caching performance most likely
>   will not occur. However, correct operation is still guaranteed.

So using the `OpenSequentialReadAsync` method can give you performance gains if you really are reading a file sequentially. There is no equivalent optimization for writing, so you can just use `OpenAsync`.